# Keras CNN low training and val acc

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

I don't what is wrong with my current network architecture maybe some of you can help.

I have a dataset that is highly imbalanced so i have implemented a datagenerator which balances the image data so there is the same number of images for each class.

I have implemented a small resnet (almost the same as in the keras documentation):

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name="img")
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu")(inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu")(x)
block_1_output = layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(block_1_output)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
block_2_output = layers.add([x, block_1_output])

x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(block_2_output)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
block_3_output = layers.add([x, block_2_output])

x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu")(block_3_output)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
#x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="toy_resnet")
model.summary()

----------

Model: "toy_resnet"Model: "toy_resnet"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
img (InputLayer)                [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 222, 222, 64) 1792        img[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 220, 220, 128 73856       conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 73, 73, 128)  0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 73, 73, 64)   73792       max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 73, 73, 128)  73856       conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add (Add)                       (None, 73, 73, 128)  0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
                                                                 max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 73, 73, 64)   73792       add[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 73, 73, 128)  73856       conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_1 (Add)                     (None, 73, 73, 128)  0           conv2d_5[0][0]                   
                                                                 add[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 71, 71, 64)   73792       add_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Globa (None, 64)           0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 256)          16640       global_average_pooling2d[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 3)            771         dense[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 462,147
Trainable params: 462,147
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I have trained it for 50 epochs and made several changes during my testing all with the same result where training accuracy and validation accuracy begins to flucturate after 20 epochs.

Do i increase the depth, increase number of neurons or train for more epochs? or is this problem more related to the learning rate where my model gets stuck in a local minima?

I have checked the data generator and the batches looks fine.

i have used the following config for training:

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
              loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])

def reduce_lr():
    return ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', 
                            factor=0.2,
                            patience=2, 
                            min_lr=0.00001)

history = model.fit(
    train_gen,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_gen,
    callbacks=[checkpoint(), reduce_lr()]
)
```

I haven't found any good articles on this particular problem since i wouldn't say my model is overfitting/underfitting yet...

[image: training]

---------------UPDATE-----------------

[image: overfit]

Do i try until i hit 100% or increase dataset right away

Comment: Given a balanced training dataset the accuracy of 64% is at least an improvement over predicting a random, so the model is able to learn some information from the data. Without knowing what type of problem you are working on, what accuracy would you expect the model be able to reach? It can simply be the case that it is simply a hard problem and the model can't do better. I would first try to overfit the model on a small subset of the data (i.e. try to get the accuracy as close to 100% as possible) and then try to generalize as best as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So maybe 100 images of each class or something or lower ? where do you usally start

Comment: Using 100 images of each class is probably fine, try to get as close to 100% accuracy as possible and then try to expand the dataset used. See also [the list of tips from Andrej Karpathy](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/) on training a neural network, mainly the point on overfitting on a single batch in section 2.

Comment: I have now increases the network parameters by a million or so and now it overfits on 70x3 images and the same for validation. Would you say 96% training acc is enough to start increasing the dataset or should i aim even higher?

Comment: It's mostly just a bit of trial and error, but I would say 96% accuracy is sufficient to try and start seeing if that performance holds over a larger part of the dataset.